# Select listings from all subcategory levels associated with a given categoryID

Tags: mysql, sql

I hope I can explain this well enough. I have four levels of category with the following table structure:

### categories (catlevel=0)

```
record_id   category
--------------------
1           Antiques & Collectibles
2           Art
3           Baby Gear
```

### subcategories (catlevel=1)

```
record_id  category_id  subcategory
----------------------------------
1          3            Baby room & furniture
2          3            Backpacks & carrier
3          3            Bath time
```

### subsubcategories (catlevel=2)

```
record_id  subcategory_id  subsubcategory
---------------------------------------
1          1               Bookcases & shelves
2          1               Cushions
3          1               Lamps & lighting
4          1               Wall hangings & paintings
```

### subsubsubcategories  (catlevel=3)

```
record_id  subsubcategory_id  subsubsubcategory
---------------------------------------------
1          4                  Animals
2          4                  Fairy tales
3          4                  Names & letters
```

I also have a listings table as follows. A listing has only one exhaustive category, i.e. when a listing is created you must define it precisely at the lowest possible category level. i.e. if there are still lower category levels you must keep selecting subcategories until there is nothing lower.

### listings

```
record_id   catid   catlevel  title
-------------------------------------------------------
1           1        3        Wooden Animal Wall Hanging
2           1        2        Wooden Book Case
3           3        1        Bubble Bath
```

`"catid"` is the unique id of whatever level we are talking about

`"catlevel"` defines the actual category level, so a level of "0" would be the top level "Categories", whereas a level of "3" would be the lowest "SubSubSubcategory" level

There is search functionality on the website front end. You enter keywords and select a top level category (catlevel=0) from a drop-down box. You can only select a top level category at this stage, none of the lower subcategory levels.

I want this search to return listings that are not only under that top level category but also any associated subcategory level right down to catlevel 3.

So for the above example, if I enter "wooden" in the search box and select "Baby Gear" from the category drop-down, I should get the first two records from the "Listings" table.

Comment: Expanding this for when you want to check lower category levels (or add more levels) is going to be a pain to do as your data isn't normalised. Those 4 tables could be made into one table if required (just add a column for level, and a dummy parent category id for records from the first table), which would enable a simple WHERE clause to be used to find a category level.

Comment: Thanks, I followed this advice. Query much faster now too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably needs to join against the listings table at each category level.

Maybe like this, checking for 'baby gear' in the high level category, finding a match on any and using coalesce to get the first level of matching details. Down side is that this will use indexes poorly (probably not an extra issue and using %....% in a like will stop the indexes being used anyway)

```
SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(b1.record_id, b2.record_id, b3.record_id) AS record_id,
        COALESCE(b1.catid , b2.catid , b3.catid ) AS catid,
        COALESCE(b1.catlevel, b2.catlevel, b3.catlevel) AS catlevel,
        COALESCE(b1.title, b2.title, b3.title) AS title
FROM categories a
INNER JOIN subcategories b ON a.record_id = b.category_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN listings b1 ON b1.catlevel = 1 AND b.record_id = b1.catid
INNER JOIN subsubcategories c ON b.record_id = c.subcategory_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN listings b2 ON b2.catlevel = 2 AND b.record_id = b2.catid
INNER JOIN subsubsubcategories d ON c.record_id = d.subsubcategory_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN listings b3 ON b3.catlevel = 3 AND b.record_id = b3.catid
WHERE a.category = 'Baby Gear'
AND (b1.title LIKE '%wooden%'
OR   b2.title LIKE '%wooden%'
OR   b3.title LIKE '%wooden%')
```

Possible to also do this with multiple queries unioned together:-

```
SELECT l.record_id, l.catid, l.catlevel, l.title
FROM categories a
INNER JOIN subcategories b ON a.record_id = b.category_id
INNER JOIN listings l ON l.catlevel = 1 AND b.record_id = l.catid
WHERE a.category = 'Baby Gear'
AND l.title LIKE '%wooden%'
OR   
UNION
SELECT l.record_id, l.catid, l.catlevel, l.title
FROM categories a
INNER JOIN subcategories b ON a.record_id = b.category_id
INNER JOIN subsubcategories c ON b.record_id = c.subcategory_id
INNER JOIN listings l ON l.catlevel = 2 AND b.record_id = l.catid
WHERE a.category = 'Baby Gear'
AND l.title LIKE '%wooden%'
UNION
SELECT l.record_id, l.catid, l.catlevel, l.title
FROM categories a
INNER JOIN subcategories b ON a.record_id = b.category_id
INNER JOIN subsubcategories c ON b.record_id = c.subcategory_id
INNER JOIN subsubsubcategories d ON c.record_id = d.subsubcategory_id 
INNER JOIN listings l ON l.catlevel = 3 AND b.record_id = l.catid
WHERE a.category = 'Baby Gear'
AND l.title LIKE '%wooden%'
```

This issue would probably be far easier to solve if the database was redesigned to use the nested set model.